# Float left but stop at certain point on screen resize?

Tags: html, css

I have a div stretching the height of my page, with float left, eg:

```
#leftvignette {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#sitecontent {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="leftvignette"></div>    
<div id="sitecontent">
    all other content here
</div>
```

I want this div to always sit at the left of my content until the window is less then 1000px wide - I dont want the `#leftvignette` to intrude and cover my content.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS Media queries and the CSS clear property to remove the float:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #leftvignette {
    clear:both;
}
}
```

Anything below 1000px will then have the float: left removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
#leftvignette {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background:#000;
}
#sitecontent {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    background:#f00;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
}
.clear{clear:both;}


<div id="leftvignette"></div>    
<div id="sitecontent">
    all other content here
</div>
<div class="clear">
<!--this will help in clearing float for next comming elements.-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create some util classes like for example `.clear` and use them whenever you need just applying the in html as class.

**CSS:**

```
.clear{
   clear:both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="leftvignette" class="clear"></div>
```

Remember to use it after float; it will clear both sides of your div so no element will be placed to the left and right of your "Box".

In your case is better if you use media queries, like that:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1000px){
     #leftvignette{
        clear:both;
     }
}
```